# Is this incorrect; am I mixing tenses here?

Tags: tenses, past-tense

Is this correct?

> I don't miss my deadlines, even when I worked for a high pressure educational software
>   company, which required quick, effective reasoning without compromising the quality of the
>   end result.

It seems equivalent to this, which sounds awful:

> Even when I worked for a high pressure educational software
>   company, which required quick, effective reasoning without compromising the quality of the
>   end result, I don't miss my deadlines.

Comment: I'm afraid we don't do proofreading, as per the [faq].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right; the tense switch is incorrect grammar.  I'd say to split the first part (which describes your habit) from the second (which describes a past event):

> I don't miss my deadlines.  Even when I worked for a high pressure educational software company, which required quick, effective reasoning without compromising the quality of the end result, I was consistently on time.

Comment: I think the mixed tenses are unquestionably "incorrect". Simplify it to *"I **am** industrious even when I **was** on holiday"* (the comma can't possibly be cited as justifying the tense switch) and it's patently nonsense.

Comment: Downvote reversed. Personally I think OP's example is a real [garden path sentence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence), in that (if you assume as I did on first reading that the comma was probably supposed to be a semicolon), you have to keep reading for ages before discovering that you've come to a full stop before reaching something like the final clause correctly added in your rephrased version.